# Need help formatting a date in MomentJS in Japanese

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, calendar, momentjs

I need help formatting a date in MomentJS

The main issue i am facing is that the Japanese “day” character `日` is not displaying

- Date: `3 Nov`.
- Actual Output: `11月 03`
- Expected Output: `11月 03日`

Format tried `MMM DD`

https://jsbin.com/caganaveci/edit?js,console

Answer (score 6):

The format argument should be `MMM Do` to append `日` to the day of month. `日` is the ordinal for the day of month.

```js
moment.locale('ja');

console.log(moment().format('MMM Do'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as an alternative, there is also *toLocaleString*:

```js
console.log(new Date(2017,10,3).toLocaleString('ja',{month:'long',day:'numeric'}));
```