# Display date in English and Japanese using moment.js or using JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs, dateformatter

I am using moment.js for formatting dates. I want to display date in 'en-JP' culture, but moment.js does not support 'en-JP' language.

Jquery/Javascript code would also be fine.

I want to display date like:

> 2018年 Aug月 15日 Wednesday

Comment: I am sure you have looked at Moment.js locale and its customization documentations. If not this link will help you finding more about your language customization

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/

Comment: "en-jp" is a language code that is interpreted as "English as spoken in Japan". Are you sure that's an actual dialect?

Comment: @RobG  no it’s not the actual dialect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need help formatting a date in MomentJS in Japanese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155774/need-help-formatting-a-date-in-momentjs-in-japanese)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems "年", "月", "日" are Japanese for "year", "month", "day" so don't change with the date. So you don't need a library if there's reasonable support for the Intl object via *toLocaleString*, e.g.

```js
var d = new Date();
var lang = 'en',
    year = d.toLocaleString(lang, {year:'numeric'}),
    month = d.toLocaleString(lang, {month:'short'}),
    day = d.toLocaleString(lang, {day:'numeric'}),
    dayName = d.toLocaleString(lang, {weekday:'long'});

console.log(
  `${year}年 ${month}月 ${day}日 ${dayName}`
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such format (2018年 Aug月 15日 Wednesday) your are asking in **Japanese culture**.

But if you really need this format only you can get it like below using momentjs:

```js
//2018年 Aug月 15日 Wednesday
var moment = moment();

console.log(moment.year() + "年 " + moment.format("MMM") + "月 " + moment.date() + "日 " + moment.format("dddd"));

console.log(moment.format('YYYY年 MMM月 D日 dddd'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, not *only* using moment.js. Added a simpler format string. ;-)